# Uploading image to server not working react native

Tags: react-native

Uploading image to a server not giving any error but not uploading and can not see it in the folder on server. here is my code

```js
    let uploadImage = async () => {
      if (selectedImage1 != null) {
        const fileToUpload = selectedImage1;
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', 'Image Upload');
        data.append('file_attachment', fileToUpload);
        let res = await fetch('https://url', {
            method: 'post',
            body: data,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; ',
            },
          }
        );
        let responseJson = await res.json();
        console.log(responseJson);
      } else {
        //if no file selected the show alert
        alert('Somthing Went Wrong!');
      }
    };
```

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; ',` <-- This is invalid/incorrect.

Comment: What is the exact type of `selectedImage1` at runtime? Is it a JS `File`/`Blob` object or something else?

Comment: `if (responseJson.status == 'success') {` <-- Your code is making assumptions about the content of the response body without first checking the response status-code and content-type (i.e. your code will fail if the server responds with a non-JSON or unexpected response): you need to always check the status-code and content-type first, and you should also wrap this all in a `try/catch/finally` to gracefully handle network errors.

Comment: selectedImage1 is file path selected from image picker

Comment: if (responseJson.status == 'success') { just leave this part for now just check if file uploads and getting anything in responseJson log. but nothing in log